# how to use .set() or .setvalue() on char in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D array of `char`s:

```
char [][] val = {{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d', 'e', 'f'}, {'g', 'h', 'i'}};
```

I want to set or update the value of it to something else by using a `.setSomething()`-method:

```
val[0][0].setValue('z');
```

The code above does not work. How may I do this (if it is possible)?

Comment: Why would you need to call a method when the humble `=` serves the purpose just fine?

Comment: A remark on your code: In Java, the array-brackets are written directly following the type, without any blanks (`char [][] val` -> `char[][] val`).

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the normal assignment operator, `=`:

```
char[][] val = {{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d', 'e', 'f'}, {'g', 'h', 'i'}};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(val));
val[0][0] = 'z';
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(val));
```

Output:

```
[[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]
[[z, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried but it didn't work. Something I forgot to add in my question was that I am working on an applet. Would that make any difference?

Comment: I doubt it, but applets are very old and shouldn't be used anymore.